# SQL Server : Bulk Insert in Transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server

Inserting bulk of records in a transaction.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION DATAINSERT

-- INSERT QUERIES HERE

COMMIT TRANSACTION DATAINSERT
```

But even though scripts in the middle of file encountered foreign key constraints, previous inserts were not rolled back.

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

All I want is scripts should succeed if and only if all inserts are successful without any constraint violations.

Comment: How about the whole script you ran? From what you posted this should be fine but the real script is obviously not working correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all errors imply rollback. It depends on [severity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164086.aspx). Sometimes you need to explicitly rollback in case of error.

Set [`SET XACT_ABORT ON`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188792.aspx) to force all errors to be transaction aborting ones, but be wary that your script does not continue expecting a transaction and auto-committing each statement after the error.